# How do I tokenize this input sentences by the following stopwords ("!", "?", ".", “,”) using split in python?

Tags: python, tokenize

My background is javascript and php. So yesterday I went for an entry level position interview that uses python. There's a test for the interview. The test is an open-book test, so I tried looking on the net and tried to understand every method use out there and the closest method that may solve the problem is by using sent_tokenize method. However, I keep on failing to get the expected output. I think that the sent_tokenize method is not the correct method to solve this. Is it possible to solve the question below by using split method?

```
Test case 1:
Input: Excuse me, where can I find a chicken rice shop? 
Expected output: ["Excuse me", "where can I find a chicken rice shop"]

Test case 2:
Input: OMG!!! It is Friday....where should we go for dinner? 
Expected output: ["OMG", "It is Friday", "where should we go for dinner"]

Test case 3:
Input: He’s nervous, but on the surface he looks calm and ready. 
Expected output: [“He’s nervous”, “but on the surface he looks calm and ready”]


from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
def tokenise(input, expected_output):
  input = "Excuse me, where can I find a chicken rice shop?"
  expected_output = ['Excuse me', 'where can I find a chicken rice shop']
  result = sent_tokenize(input)
print('Pass' if result == expected_output else 'Failed!')

# Please make sure all test cases return 'Pass'
tokenise(tcase1, tans1)
tokenise(tcase2, tans2)
tokenise(tcase3, tans3)
print('Pass' if result == expected_output else 'Failed!')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

```
import re

re.split(r"[!?., ]+", text)
```

Answer (score 0):

First step, using re.split to split the text.

```
input = "Excuse me, where can I find a chicken rice shop?"
result = re.split(r"[!?.,]+", input)
print(result)

['Excuse me', ' where can I find a chicken rice shop', '']
```

The second text having space in front of the text, so you will need to remove it.

```
result = [x.strip() for x in result]
print(result)

['Excuse me', 'where can I find a chicken rice shop', '']
```

Third step, remove the blank.

```
result = [x for x in result if x != '']
print(result)

['Excuse me', 'where can I find a chicken rice shop']
```

So your code will be:

```
def Strip(input):
    result = re.split(r"[!?.,]+", input)
    return [x.strip() for x in result if x != '']
```

**Edit Add On Validation*

```
def validation(input,expected_output):
    # input = "Excuse me, where can I find a chicken rice shop?"
    # expected_output = ['Excuse me', 'where can I find a chicken rice shop']
    result = Strip(input)
    print('Pass' if result == expected_output else 'Failed!')

# Test case 1:
Input = "Excuse me, where can I find a chicken rice shop?"
Expected_output = ["Excuse me", "where can I find a chicken rice shop"]

validation(Input, Expected_output)

# Test case 2:
Input = "OMG!!! It is Friday....where should we go for dinner?"
Expected_output = ["OMG", "It is Friday", "where should we go for dinner"]

validation(Input, Expected_output)

# Test case 3:
Input = "He’s nervous, but on the surface he looks calm and ready."
Expected_output = ["He’s nervous", "but on the surface he looks calm and ready"]

validation(Input, Expected_output)
```

Comment: I triede running the code above but not working, https://paste.pics/JILOB

Comment: You type input = "Excuse me, where can I find a chicken rice shop?" , then Strip(input)

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to other solutions that use regular expressions, you may wish to use `re.escape` and `re.compile` to build a compiled regular expression from an input string of delimiters.

```
import re

def split_on(s, delimiters):
  r = re.compile(f'[{re.escape(delimiters)}]+')
  return [x.strip() for x in r.split(s) if x != '']
```

```
>>> split_on("He’s nervous, but on the surface he looks calm and ready.", "!?.,")
['He’s nervous', 'but on the surface he looks calm and ready']
```